# restarting the Gunicorn after change in my code

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have killed the process of gunicorn using `pkill gunicorn`. In my server i have pulled the chanded code from git. And then i killed the gunicorn so that I can see my changes..

Now how can I again start gunicorn. I am using nginx and gunicorn. When I access the url I see 502 Bad Gateway error.

Answer (score 1):

You can restart gunicorn if you are in ubuntu:

```
sudo service restart gunicorn
```

As you have killed the process you need to start it:

```
sudo service gunicorn start
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for Gunicorn
http://gunicorn.org/#quickstart.

If you'd followed the tutorial this line shows how to restart your unicorn service...

```
gunicorn -w 4 your_app:app
```